# how can i make a conditional sort for storting a list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, conditional-statements

I have been trying to sort this list in a way that it should first sort based on the second item of the tuples but if two tuples have the same second item it should sort based on the first item alphabetically

```
patient_list: list[tuple] = [("Johnson", 9), ("Smith", 2), ("Perry", 4), ("Allison", 8), ("Bradley", 1), ("Tucker", 9)]

def sort(patient_list: list[tuple]) -> list[tuple]:
    """ 
    
    """


    patient_list = sorted(patient_list, key=lambda y: y[1])

    print(patient_list)

sort(patient_list)
```

i tried this first but it doesnt work:

```
patient_list: list[tuple] = [("Johnson", 9), ("Smith", 2), ("Perry", 4), ("Allison", 8), ("Bradley", 1), ("Tucker", 9)]

def sort(patient_list: list[tuple]) -> list[tuple]:
    """ 
    
    """
    patient_list = sorted(patient_list, key=lambda t: t[0])

    patient_list = sorted(patient_list, key=lambda y: y[1])

    print(patient_list)

sort(patient_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to phrase the problem statement as the function that you pass as `key=`.

```
patient_list.sort(key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))
```

This works because tuples sort the way you would expect. Since you want the data sorted in-place in `patient_list`, use `.sort()` instead of `sorted()`.